# What is the correct way to track and monitor Exchange DB replication "pressure" over time?

Tags: performance, exchange-2010, performance-tuning

I want to determine if some databases are overloaded or unbalanced, and think that looking at the transaction logs created per database over time would tell me which DB is at risk of missing RPO targets due to high IO (mostly writes).

My thought is to create a graph of each database, every X minutes and count each log that is created.

Since each log = 1MB in an E2010 DAG, I can easily calculate the amount of data that could be lost in a given time.

So my question is:

1. How can I determine if a given database has extra IO that might be better moved to a lower volume database? Is transaction logs a valid way of looking at it?
2. How should I procedurally figure out the load?  Perhaps a powershell script, C#, and export that to a graph or excel.

Comment: Can you define "unneeded IO?" If the IO is generated, it is needed for *something*.

Comment: @MDMarra - Fixed.

Comment: Sorry, still not understanding what you are looking for. Are you trying to identify low-usage mailboxes so that you can move them to a database on slower disk? Are you trying to find high-usage mailboxes to move them to faster disk? Do you just want to profile IO over time for mailboxes in a given database? Or something else all together?

Comment: @MDMarra All disks are the same.  The problem I'm seeing is that our bandwidth isn't capable of maintaining a realistic RPO due to many logs being created.  This results in one particular database lag behind the others.  I would rather spread out the load across all databases so that this one DB doesn't stick out during a failover event... and may need to be restored from tape because replication is.. well useless for this DB.

Comment: Ok, so I will ask one more time. **What metrics are you looking to retrieve from this mail database?** Are you looking for the busiest mailboxes so that you can move them to other databases? If your throughput is an issue, all that this will do is cause your replication lag to be spread more evenly, it won't make it go away.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - I'm kind of lost as to how spreading the load would help.  Given 10 1MB trans logs for a DB, if you spread it out to 3, 3, 4 across 3 DBs, that's still the same 10MB of logs that has to be replicated across (assuming) the same pipe.  Right?

Comment: @MDMarra Our core issue is that Log LUNs are filling up at an abnormally high rate, and so I guess I need to figure out which mailbox-specific metric relates to logs created.

Comment: Every transaction creates a log entry. Mail item received, mail item sent, calendar items, etc etc etc. A very good start would be to get inbound/outbound mail per (day|hour|minute) for each mailbox in that database. Your highest ranking mailboxes will be responsible for the highest amount of log activity

Comment: @TheCleaner The WAN bandwidth constraint is preventing the timely truncation of logs (I think logs are only truncated when a full backup occurs and the data has been replicated to each DAG member).  It eventually does catch up, but not often enough for us to get scarily close to filling the drive.  I think that by moving active mailboxes to other LUNs, the replication issue will still exist, however the disk space issue will be temporarily relieved.

Comment: Ahh...gotcha, so like @MDMarra said, you want to move some users to databases where those databases tran logs are stored on a different LUN than what you currently have them on, correct?

Comment: Yes, it seems that @MDMarras logic would be correct, I have 5 databases / logs on the same lun.  Rather than graphing the log files per hour it makes more sense to generally identify the heavy hitters in that DB set in general, and move them.  I'll be parsing logs soon.  Thanks both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you can use the great info here: http://penetrateit.wordpress.com/2012/02/11/exchange-2010-balancing-the-number-of-mailboxes-and-average-size-across-all-databases/ to figure out some stats needed to help balance the mailboxes across databases.

Or you can use Steve's script here: http://www.stevieg.org/2010/09/balancing-exchange-databases/

However, Let me suggest an additional approach:

- if you haven't already, setup your DBs based on RPO.  Meaning create a VIP database, and so on.  Put those VIPs together in a DB that you know will get replicated well across the WAN and use LUNs that won't fill up for this DB.  (HOWEVER, note that you don't want to go crazy and put all your high-use users into the VIP DB, or you'll compound your issue).  By VIP, I'm referring to people where the RPO is "the last hour" or similar.  You can even make a "Meh RPO" db and stick a bunch of non-essential mailboxes in there that you don't care much about regarding RPO, then if you have the means to do so on your WAN de-prioritize their replication traffic.

Hope that helps.